# Existe try-with-resource no PHP?

Tags: php, php-7, try-with-resources

Existe no PHP algo parecido com **try with resource** do Java? Ou tenho que fechar recursos no bloco do `finally` mesmo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não, em essência não precisa. Primeiro que PHP é uma linguagem de *script* tudo roda por alguns segundos, quando muito, geralmente é uma fração disto, então não liberar um recurso não faz diferença. E mesmo que precise liberar logo ele até costuma fazer porque o *garbage collector* dele é baseado em contagem de referência, que permite uma finalização determinística, então assim que o objeto não tem um referência para ele já é coletado e pode liberar os recursos, diferente do Java que tem um coletor de lixo baseado em rastreamento e a liberação só pode ocorrer quando o GC entra em ação, por isso precisa de um outro mecanismo para liberar antes, por isso foi criado o `try-resource`.

Ao contrário do Java, o PHP não tem, acertadamente, ou não tinha a cultura de uso de exceções como em Java. E não precisa fazer para liberar qualquer recurso (em quase todos os casos).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Vlw Maniero mato minha dúvida ;)

Answer (score -5):

A pequena diferença da linguagem PHP que é uma linguagem não tipada, para outras linguagens fortemente tipadas, é que ela é interpretada não necessitando utilizar a exemplo do C#, o using para liberar recurso da memória, ao você executar uma linha de código ela automaticamente irá executar a linha e liberar o recurso assim que o escopo da função finalizar.